# Count the number of observations in the data frame in R

Tags: r, counting

I want to know the way of counting the number of observations using R.
For example, let's say I have a data `df` as follows:

`df <- data.frame(id = c(1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,5,5,5,9,9))`
Even though the biggest number of `id` is 9, there are only 5 numbers: 1,2,3,5,and 9.  So there are only 5 numbers in `id`. I want to count how many numbers exist in `id`   like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `base R`:

```
length(unique(df$id))
[1] 5
```

Here, `unique` filters only distinct values and `length` then counts the number of values in the vector

In `dplyr`:

```
df %>%
  summarise(n = length(unique(id)))
```

Alternatively:

```
nrow(distinct(df))
```

Here, `distinct` subsets the *whole dataframe* (not just the column `id`!) to unique rows before `nrow` counts the number of remaining rows

Answer (score 1):

Here another two options:

```r
df <- data.frame(id = c(1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,5,5,5,9,9))

sum(!duplicated(df$id))
#> [1] 5
library(dplyr) 
n_distinct(df$id)
#> [1] 5
```

<sup>Created on 2022-07-09 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>